# In Datatable excel export, decimal values with % symbol are getting rounded off excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatables

I am trying to export Datatable to excel sheet. Datatable has a column with decimal values and % symbol. After exporting, the decimal values are getting rounded off. But I need decimal values with % symbol to be present in the excel sheet. Can anyone help me with it. Thanks.
[JSFiddle][1]

Table:

9.09%   7.88%   9.99%   8.38%   8.13%   7.57%   9.30%   8.95%   -0.37%

9.09%   7.88%   9.99%   8.38%   8.13%   7.57%   9.30%   8.95%   -0.37%

33.41%  30.42%  29.14%  34.44%  31.85%  32.14%  34.12%  34.98%  1.48%

8.98%   8.09%   7.70%   9.87%   9.35%   6.93%   8.98%   6.08%   -0.78%

10.30%  11.38%  13.32%  12.40%  11.80%  13.64%  16.15%  13.42%  1.92%

exported excel

9%  8%  10% 8%  8%  8%  9%  9%  0%

9%  8%  10% 8%  8%  8%  9%  9%  0%

33% 30% 29% 34% 32% 32% 34% 35% 1%

9%  8%  8%  10% 9%  7%  9%  6%  -1%

10% 11% 13% 12% 12% 14% 16% 13% 2%

Comment: for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/nLpoajbz/

Answer (score 1):

The data in the generated .xlsx file includes the full decimal precision from the DataTable. This can be seen by opening the generated .xlsx container as a .zip file, then going into the `xl` then `worksheets` directories and opening `sheet1.xml`. The data for row 3 starts as:

```xml
<row r="3">
  <c r="A3" s="56">
    <v>0.1223</v>
  </c>
  <c r="B3" s="56">
    <v>1.6022999999999998</v>
  </c>
  <c r="C3" s="56">
    <v>0.10263</v>
  </c>
  ...
```

In this data structure the attribute `s` represents the style that is being used, in this case set to "56". The styles are contained within the .xls container in the file named `styles.xml` within the `xl` directory. The number is the index of the style within `cellXfs`, a sample of the styles data from this file is:

```xml
<cellXfs count="68">
  <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1" />
  <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="1" fillId="0" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1" />
  ...
```

The styles which the DataTables excelHtml5 button adds by default are listed out in the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Customisation). This shows "56" is '56 - Percentage integer value (automatically detected and used by buttons - since 1.2.3)'. excelHtml5 adds a built in style for percentage with 1 decimal place as number "60", but it doesn't have one for percentage with two decimal places.

To get two decimal places a new style must be added. The OpenXML file format already has a number format ID for percentage with two decimal places, based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.numberingformat) it is numFmtId="10". This number format can be used in the new style (else a new number format would have to added also).

The new style using the numFmtId="10" must be added to the styles.xml document, then the index of the newly added style used on the cells. Sample code to achieve this is below:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  filename: "abc",
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    text: 'Excel',
    customize: function(xlsx) {
      //Get the styles sheet
      let styles = xlsx.xl['styles.xml'];

      // Create a style which uses numFmtId=10, this is the format for percentage with 2 decimal places
      let style = '<xf numFmtId="10" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1"/>';
      
      // Get the current cellXfs
      let cellXfs = $('cellXfs', styles);

      // Append the style to cellXfs, and update the cellXfs count attribute
      cellXfs.append(style);
      cellXfs.attr('count', $('xf', cellXfs).length);
      
      // Get sheet 1 and apply the new style, skipping first two rows.
      // The last element in cellXfs is the ID which is used as the value of s
      let sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
      $('row:gt(1) c', sheet).attr('s', $('xf', cellXfs).length - 1);
    }
  }]
});
```

A working sample based off the one you provided in the question can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/sg94ec2u/.